# Update or insert issues in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've unique rows with primary key in my `emp` table.

```
select * from EMP E;
```

Now I've created `emp_backup` table which takes backup of `emp` table like.

```
insert into emp_backup
select * from emp e
where not exists (select EMPNO from emp_backup E1 where E1.EMPNO=e.EMPNO);
```

the above query successfully copies all the rows from `emp` to `emp_backup` and it make sure when you again run above query it will not copy the existing rows from `emp` to `emp_backup` table in next run.

now my problem is when i update any record in `emp` table and try to run above query it gives me error of `primary key violation` which is excepted.

for example.

```
update  EMP
set JOB='worker'
where   EMPNO=14;
```

I update `emp` table after copying the record with `empno` 14 to emp_backup table.

when i run `insert into emp_backup....` query i want this update change should refelect into `emp_backup` table.

How can i modify the above query so that it will copy the updated rows with existing primary key from `emp` to `emp_backup`.

I hope my question is clear, tell me how i can improve it.

Comment: Have you defined any other column as the unique key or primary key in emp_backup

Comment: @SathyaNarayanan I've only `empno` as primary key in both `emp` and `emp_backup` table.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a backup?  You could use full as well as differential for options...

Comment: @OMGPonies I want to do using sql queries only that is the requirement.

Comment: If `EMPNO` is your PK, and you check that `EMPNO` doesn't exist in your `emp_backup` table before adding it... why would it be expected that you would get a PK violation when running that query more than once?

Comment: Also, is queries your requirement because that's what you're familiar with, or is there some other reason?  What about snapshots?

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson I've updated my question with my update query please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when you created your emp_backup table, that you also created a table PK on the EMPNO table. This will prevent you from inserting the same emp record twice.

You need to rethink your 'backup' plan - do you want

1. a running audit of every version of every record change in the emp table
2. a mirror of the emp table exactly?

For 1:

- Drop the primary key on emp_backup table. This will allow duplicate emp records to be copied into it. If you need idempotence on the emp_backup table, you could create a new surrogate PK (e.g. `emp_backup_id int identity(1,1)`, and possibly a new `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` defaulted column to assist you in determining which is the latest

After dropping your PK, updated records can be 'backed up' as:

```
insert into emp_backup 
select * from emp e 
where exists 
  (select EMPNO 
   from emp_backup E1 
   where E1.EMPNO=e.EMPNO
   and 
   (e1.othercolumn1 <> e.othercolumn1
   or e1.othercolumn2 <> e.othercolumn2
   ...
   )
); .
```

(Note that columns of certain types can't be compared directly)

For 2, you would need to update existing records in your emp_bak table:

```
update eb
set eb.othercolumn1 = e.othercolumn1,
    eb.othercolumn2 = e.othercolumn2
from emp_backup eb
    inner join emp e on eb.empno = e.empno
where 
   eb.othercolumn1 <> e.othercolumn1
   or eb.othercolumn2 <> e.othercolumn2
   ...
); .
```

But your table mirroring begs the question, everytime you want a backup, why not just drop your existing emp_backup table and do:

```
insert into emp_backup 
select * from emp e
```

??

Comment: I can't drop backup table which contains more than million records every time.

Comment: In that case use a trigger to audit as @Karl suggests, or otherwise just entrust your data to backups like OMGPonies commented.

Answer (score 1):

in order to collect all change you will need a history (or audit) table.  create a triger on your table that writes a record to including an activity-time field the history table with each change. then select from the history table when activity-time field greater than last backup query.

thizs will enable you to collect all update insert and deletes

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using SQL Server 2008, you can make use of the [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) command.

This one command will let you add records when they don't exist in your backup table, and update them to match when they do exist.

[Here's an example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522.aspx):

```
MERGE emp_backup AS T
USING emp AS S
ON (T.EMPNO = S.EMPNO) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT(EMPNO, JOB) VALUES(S.EMPNO, S.JOB)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET T.JOB = S.JOB
```